# Proving that $R_1 = R_2$ (linearly ordered sets)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be linearly ordered sets in set $X$.
Prove that if $R_1R_2$ is linearly ordered set, then $R_1 = R_2$

I understand the defnitions of $R_1R_2$ and totally ordered sets, but when I start to prove, it seems that I still lack some knowledge. Definitions don't seem to be enough.

Comment: What is $R_1R_2$?

Comment: Are you [the same user who asked this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555499/proving-strict-linear-relation-in-a-set)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$xR_{1}R_{2}z \iff  xR_{2}y$  and $yR_{1}z$ for some $y$.

Assume that $xR_{2}z$. It is to be shown that $xR_{1}z$ and since $R_{1}$ is linear we have $xR_{1}z$ or $zR_{1}x$. In the first case we are ready.

If $zR_{1}x$ then we combine this with $zR_{2}z$ and find $zR_{1}R_{2}x$.Next to that we have $xR_{2}z$ and $zR_{1}z$ leading to $xR_{1}R_{2}z$. Then $x=z$ and consequently $xR_{1}z$.

Proved is now that $R_{2}\subset R_{1}$ and likewise it can be shown that $R_{1}\subset R_{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** If $R_1\neq R_2$ then there is an ordered pair $(a,b)\in R_1$ such that $(a,b)\notin R_2$. Since $R_2$ is linear, $(b,a)\in R_2$. Use the fact that $(b,b)$ is in both relations to conclude that the composition is not antisymmetric.

Comment: I tried that, but wasn't able to come to a conclusion.

For example: $X={a,b}$,  $R_1={(a,a),(b,b),(a,b)}$, $R_2={(a,a),(b,b),(b,a)}$ and therefore $R_1R_2$ could equal ${(a,a),(b,b),(b,a)}$. Where am I wrong?
Why are $R_1$, $R_2$,

Comment: Is your definition for a linear order requires reflexivity, or is it strict linear order where $(x,x)\notin R$ for all $x\in X$?

Comment: It requires reflexivity.

Comment: You computed the composition of the orders wrong. You're missing one more ordered pair created from $(a,b)\in R_1$ and $(b,b)\in R_2$.